# AJAX using JSON

Tags: json

The button is supposed to display brett under Name and Australia under country in the divs with the same names on click, but I can't get it to work. Here is the code:
html with script:

```
<html>
 <head><meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
 <script type="APPLICATION/javascript">
 function loadJSON(){    var data_file = "data.json"; 
 var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 try{
  // Opera 8.0+, FIREFOX, Chrome, Safari
  http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();}catch (e){
  // Internet Explorer Browsers
  try{
     http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }catch (e) {
     try{
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("MICROSOFT.XMLHTTP");
     }catch (e){
        // Something went wrong
        alert("Your browser broke!");
        RETURN false;
     }
  }
 }
 http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
  if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
  {
    // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

    // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
    // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
    DOCUMENT.getElementById("Name").innerHTML =  jsonObj.name;
    document.getElementById("Country").innerHTML = jsonObj.country;
       }
   }
  http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
   http_request.send();
}
</script>
<title>tutorialspoint.com JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Cricketer Details</h1>
<table class="src">
 <tr><th>Name</th><th>Country</th></tr>
<tr><td><div id="Name">Sachin</div></td>
<td><div id="Country">India</div></td></tr>
</table>

<div class="central">
<button type="button" onclick="loadJSON()">UPDATE Details </button>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file with the name data.json:

```
  {
      "name": "brett",
     "country": "Australia"
  }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function `json` with a `$.getJSON(json, function(data){` method inside it and call this function with your`<button type="button" onclick="json()">UPDATE Details </button>`

You can take a look here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-getjson.htm, it helped me a lot ;)

Comment: yes, I could do that, but I am trying to learn javascript and not jquery